# Why does KDE's Konsole not have top-level menu-accelerator keys? Is it a bug? Is there a workaround?

Tags: shortcut-keys, kde, menu

I am using Ubuntu 10.04 Lucid (32).

I have installed KDE's `Konsole` (terminal), as it offers a couple of things I can't currently get in the gnome-terminal.

However there is a fly in the soup... On any day of the week, I prefer to use the keyboard over the mouse; wherever possible... but for some reason `Konsole's` menu does **not** respond to the typical (and expected) <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> to open up the File menu, etc...

To see if it was just a conflict between `Konsole` and the `gnome desktop`, I donwloaded Kubuntu 10.04, and installed it into a VM... with the same result: **No menu accelerators** for `Konsole` (only)!

All other KDE apps seem to have normally functional menu-accelerator keys... so I am left wondering why **konsole** is different!?  ... and is there a fix for this?

**Update:**  The accelerators in question refer to the **first** menu-level only. ie to the items shown in menu-**bar** (not in the sub-menus).

Comment: In gnome-terminal there is a setting for that (I have Alt+... & the whole menu disabled myself, as I never use it), I don't know about Konsole though.

Comment: Aha! ... This seems to explain WHY... I had a niggling feeling that it might be related to a hot-key clash with the "normal" functioning of a non-BU

Comment: Aha! ... This seems to explain WHY... I had a niggling feeling that it might be related to a hot-key clash with the "normal" functioning of a terminal..   Alt-F is forward one word on the command line...  Okay, thanks: now to  find the workaround (if there is one) ... (A side-issue: This comment box auto-sends my half completed comment whens I switch windows, or Compiz-zoom, or some other reason... hence, my incomplete message above...

Comment: @fedt.bear if you found a solution you can answer+accept your own question.. This way it doesn't look like it's unanswered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `terminal` is often used by *child* programs such as Vi/Vim and Emacs, etc...

These programs run directly in the terminal, and have their own sets of shortcut-keys... These app-specific shortcut-keys sometimes utilize the same <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, etc keys as are used by a *conventional GUI* app's **menu bar accelerator-keys** (eg. Kate, gedit, etc).

Also the *terminal's* native line-editing keybindings use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (word forward), <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> (word back), <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> (swap words), etc ... which also conflict with the typical first-level menu shortcut-keys of a conventional GUI app.

To prevent the loss of functionality to these apps (including `konsole` itself), the developers have simply disabled the first-level of menu-accelerators.

Although this first-level of menu accelerator keys has fallen by the wayside, virtually all sub-level items of Konsole's menu structure have their own accelerator key (by default)...  Also, it is very easy to add/modify any menu item's accelerator-key via a right-click option..

This means that all menu-items (or as many as I wish to assign)  are accessible via the keyboard...

This effectively gives full and complete keyboard access to all menu items... Allbeit in a slightly different way... (but that's because the Terminal ***is*** different).

[Click for a related link](http://saschpe.wordpress.com/2010/05/06/konsoles-user-interface-changes/)

Answer (score 3):

I am using Kubuntu 17.04. Konsole 16.12.3  Accelerator keys are turned off by default.

They can be activated by **Settings Menu > Configure Konsole > General Tab > Enable menu accelerators**.  This will enable the main menu accelerator keys (File, Edit, View, Bookmarks, Settings, Help).  The submenu accelerator keys are enabled whether the main accelerator keys are enabled or not.